# Unsupervised Algorithm for hybrid data

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, unsupervised-learning, data-science-model

I have a hybrid data that contains 15 categorical data and 4 continuous data.
I need to implement a prediction on the data. So as I don't have any labeled data, I need to implement the unsupervised algorithm.

Now Using PCA my dimensions reduced to 5 but still it has 3 categorical and 2 continuous data. Now to create a prediction algorithm, I can use KMeans for continuous data or KModes for categorical data, But I couldn't find any algorithm that works on both types of data.

Can anyone know any algorithm that works on both the data types for unsupervised prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `K-prototype algorithm`